# does setImageEdgeInsets effect setTitleEdgeInsets? why the title's left inset should be negative to let title centerd in button

Tags: image, uibutton, title, uiedgeinsets

I want to show image and title both in a button, then i try the setImageEdgeInsets and setTitleEdgeInsets.But it makes me confused.

Before setting the insets property, the button likes below ( ***Black*** rect represent the button bounds, ***Red*** rect represent the image rect, ***Green*** rect represent the title rect.)

Additional Description: My image's actual size is twice of i use， which means

```
**  [image size].width = imageWidth * 2  **
```

### [image]

then i use setImageEdgeInsets function, to set image rect

```
    [btn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake((btnHeight-titleHeight-imageHeight)/2.0,
                                              (btnWidth-imageWidth)/2,
                                              titleHeight+(btnHeight-titleHeight-imageHeight)/2.0,
                                              (btnWidth-imageWidth)/2)];
```

Now the button likes this

### [image]

Then i use setTitleEdgeInsets function, to set title rect

I first think code should be:

```
[btn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(btnHeight-titleHeight, 0, 0, 0)];
```

but the button in fact likes this

### [image]

i also try code:

```
[btn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(btnHeight-titleHeight, -imageWidth, 0, 0)];
```

Button now likes this

### [image]

Then i try code:

```
[btn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(btnHeight-titleHeight, -imageWidth*2, 0, 0)];
```

It's effective!

### [image]

But i'm confused now! why the title's left inset should be negative? and why does it related to image's width?